# GridMvc - display content in cell

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I use GridMvc and I want to add column where content in cell will be display independent to one property.

When `IsBase` is true then should be display empty string in other side `url.action`

`columns.Add().SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(d => d.IsBase ? "" :  (string)(x => @<a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Categories", new { @id = x.Id })'><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>));`

> Error:
>   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda expression is returning a lambda expression cast to a string, instead of just returning a string:

```
.RenderValueAs(
    d => d.IsBase ? "" :             /* first lambda */ 
        (string)(                    /* string cast */
            x => @<a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Categories", new { @id = x.Id })'><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
        )
);
```

I suspect you want something like the following:

```
.RenderValueAs(
    d => d.IsBase ? "" : @<a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Categories", new { @id = d.Id })'><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
);
```